# SQL recursive cte by comparing between rows

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

hi could you please help to resolve the below scenario, i need to do the update only after comparing all rows related to custid 100 and decide who has the latest date (100 or 400) that id should remain active,my existing update statement updates based on single row comparison . Could you please help in how we can do this with recursion and fire the update in the same query?

**TABLE**

```
   ID   CustID    MCustID Date        MDate
   1    100       200     2017-01-10  2017-01-15 
   2    100       300     2017-01-10  2017-01-07
   3    100       400     2017-01-10  2017-01-21
```

**CODE**

```
update A
set active = 0
from Cust A inner join tblMatch M
on A.CustomerID = case when M.Date < M.MDate then M.CustId else M.MCustId     end
```

Comment: You should always include an example of what you're trying to do, it helps avoid translation errors. Such as in this instance, I understand you simply want to join each record by latest MDate per CustID only? If that's the case, you don't need recursion, just a grouped join. In any case, your case expression returns the same M.CustId either way, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Your sample data contains a single table, while your update statement contains two tables, and your case is meaningless since both the `then` and the `else` returns the same column. Please edit your question to include all relevant tables DDL, sample data as DML, and desired output.